# Display unread messages per subcribed Yammer group

Tags: api, count, yammer

In the Yammer app on mobile as well as in the desktop version a count of the unread messages is shown for each group. I cannot find how to retreive this information from the API.

How can I show the number of unread messages for each group for every user?

A workaround using https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/:group_id.json with newer_than parameter will not suffice as the counts will not be synchronised between the Yammer site and my app.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?